# UITableView static cell resize for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, resize, iphone-5

I have seen the many threads on dealing with the iPhone 5 screen, and I have a Default-568h@2x.png added. The top view of my App resizes accordingly, but I have a container that contains a UITableViewController with static cells that gets more cells added when run on the iPhone 5. I need to have the static cells resize along with the rest of the app, so they occupy the same screen area.

Storyboard lets you toggle between 3.5 and 4 inch layout, but the changes you make carry over to the other, unlike when you rotate the view to adjust layout for screen rotation....

I found a lot about adding a second storyboard for the 5, but this seems like an inefficient way to do it. Is there any other way to get the static cells to resize accordingly? Thank you much!

[image]

Comment: Might I ask why you don't want the extra cells?

Comment: I only have 5 selections to make.... I don't need to have 6 cells...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `rowHeight` of your tableView to `self.tableView.frame.size.height / 5`

Comment: thanks. edited heightForRowAtIndexPath to return self.tableView.frame.size.height / 5 and it worked perfectly.